# Find all firestore document with specific range

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have document in Firestore that has "from" and "to" fields.
I want to find all documents that are touching the given range
for example:

```
Doc 1
  from: 2
  to: 4
  
Doc 2
  from: 4
  to: 8
  
Doc 3
  from: 7
  to: 10
  
Doc 4
  from: 3
  to: 5
  
Doc 5
  from: 1
  to: 2
```

```
Range
  from: 3
  to: 6
```

So the result is: Doc 1, Doc 2, Doc 4

Is there any way to do this in Firestore?

I've provided the image for better understanding

[image: Example]

I've tried this code

```
.where('from', '>=', 3)
.where('to', '<=', 6)
```

But the problem is, if one of the conditions is not fulfilled, then the document will not included

Note: the data type of "from" and "to" fields is Long

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to perform range conditions on multiple fields in Firestore queries. All range conditions in a single query must be on the same field.

A possible workaround is to store an array of slots that the document touches, so:

- Doc 1: `slots: [2, 3, 4]`
- Doc 2: `slots: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`
- Doc 3: `slots: [7, 8, 9, 10]`
- Doc 4: `slots: [3, 4, 5]`
- Doc 5: `slots: [1, 2]`

Then you can use an [`array-contains-any` condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) to catch the documents with any of the slots in your range:

```
collectionRef.where('slotsField', 'array-contains-any', [3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question.

The problem is, the data type of the "from" and "to" is Long, so it's impossible to store the range to the Firestore.

It's actually a timestamp I get from Date.getTime(). Should I consider to change the data structure? If yes, how it would look like

Comment: Using a slots based approach as I have above is the only approach I know of. If that can't be applied to your use-case, consider switching to a database that **does** support the querying requirements of your use-case.